# Fetching keys based on a values of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been practicing python for the first time and I encountered this doubt. With a variable text, I inputed a small paragraph and split it based on spaces. So now I have words of that paragraph, but this is stored in a dictionary. Next I went on to find the number occurences of each word in the paragraph. My ultimate motive is to make a new list of words that appear more than 'x' number of times.

My code is:

```
text = '''Population refers to the number of individuals in a particular 
place. It could be the number of humans or any other life form living in a 
certain specified area. The number of tigers living in a forest is 
therefore referred to as the population of tigers in the forest. The 
number of people living in a town or city or an entire country is the 
human population in that particular area.'''

words = text.split(" ")
a = dict()
for word in words:
  if word not in a:
    a[word] = 1
  else:
    a[word]+= 1

newlist = list()
val = 7
for key,value in a.items():
  if a[key]>val:
    newlist.append(i)
```

The final output that I receive after executing the last line is:

```
['years.', 'years.', 'years.', 'years.']
```

I don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: I'm actually getting an empty list. BTW shouldn't it be `newlist.append(i)` instead of `lisat.append(i)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a mistake I did while copying my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a dict with words as keys and number of occurences as values, you need to get all unique words first. You can do that by using the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) function of Python.

Then, you iterate over that set and by using the [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method of `list`, you can get the number of occurences for each word.

You can see that below:

```
text = '''Population refers to the number of individuals in a particular 
place. It could be the number of humans or any other life form living in a 
certain specified area. The number of tigers living in a forest is 
therefore referred to as the population of tigers in the forest. The 
number of people living in a town or city or an entire country is the 
human population in that particular area.'''

words = text.split() # Split text and create a list of all words
wordset = set(words) # Get all unique words
wordDict = dict((word,words.count(word)) for word in wordset) # Create dictionary of words and number of occurences.

for key, value in wordDict.items():
    print(key + ' : ' + str(value))
```

This will give you:

```
individuals : 1
forest : 1
the : 5
could : 1
therefore : 1
place. : 1
form : 1
or : 3
country : 1
population : 2
humans : 1
The : 2
city : 1
living : 3
Population : 1
life : 1
in : 6
a : 4
refers : 1
tigers : 2
is : 2
to : 2
be : 1
an : 1
other : 1
as : 1
particular : 2
number : 4
human : 1
It : 1
any : 1
forest. : 1
town : 1
that : 1
certain : 1
of : 5
entire : 1
people : 1
specified : 1
referred : 1
area. : 2
```

Then you can apply your own filters to get all words that appear more than `x` times.

Comment: I ran by the documentation for set, and I am still confused with it's significance. Compared to my code, why is set different and why does it work and my code does not?

Comment: `set` takes a list and removes all duplicate elements, keeping every element only one time. Running your code, produces an empty list and that is because no element has occured more than `7` times. A small remark, since you're iterating using `items()`, you can directly use the value of the item currently iterated and change your condition to `if value>val`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Also, the section of my code, where I declare an empty dictionary "a", uptil a[word]+=1, shouldn't it do the same of what set does?

Comment: Yes, it would do exactly the same as set does, you just have to check for each item if it's already in the dictiorary or not.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the piece of code you wrote where you are creating a dictionary is somewhat complex and new to me. As to how I understand it is like, for every word in the wordset, use the word, count it's size and add them to the dictionary. Is this correct from what I have understood or it means something else?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it does. If this line of code confuses you, take a look at [list comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#id6).